# ASHWID malfunction?

Tags: c#

On two machines I have **a strange problem with the ASHWID**.

This code is used to return a string with the current ASHWID:

```
public static string GetDeviceId()
{
  HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
  IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;
  DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);
 var bytes = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(hardwareId.Length)];
 dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
 return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

I use the code in a WinStore-App to get the ASHWID.

1. One customer gets a ASHWID **without any disk part** (part 3). **His machine has 4 disks installed** and Windows 10 is running.
2. Another customer has a "Microsoft Surface Pro 3" with Windows 10 running. But every 1 or 2 days the bios part (part 9) is changing.

   ASHWID at **14th Dec 2015:** 03-00-4C-41-08-00-FC-76-05-00-DA-1B-06-00-01-00-04-00-88-92-04-00-74-A8-04-00-B2-B2-01-00-F4-77-02-00-BA-9F-**09-00-A4-5F**

   ASHWID at **15th Dec 2015**: 03-00-4C-41-08-00-FC-76-05-00-DA-1B-06-00-01-00-04-00-88-92-04-00-74-A8-04-00-B2-B2-01-00-F4-77-02-00-BA-9F-**09-00-E4-86**

I am very confused by this strange behavior.

Is that a bug in Windows 10? Or is there any idea?

;-)

Best regards
Thomas